# Julia's dictionary method `haskey` returning false when key is present

Tags: dictionary, equality, julia

I am new to Julia and I am not sure why the last line evaluates to false:

```
type Point{T}
  x::T
  y::T
end

D = [Point(1.,2.) => 42]
haskey(D, Point(1., 2.))  #False!
```

Clearly the key exists so what's going on here!?

**Edit.**

If I don't use a class `Point`, it works fine:

```
D = [(1.,2.) => 42]
haskey(D, (1., 2.))  #True!
```

Can we not use classes for dictionary key types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

But look at this:

```
type Point{T}
  x::T
  y::T
end
P = Point(1., 2.)
D = [P => 42]
haskey(D, P)
```

evaluates to `true`.

It does work if you use the same object, but it does not work if you use 2 objects with the same field values. Note that objects defined using `type` are mutable, so even after you used a `Point` as a key, you could have still changed the values of its fields without the dictionary knowing. The dictionary needs to hash on something that cannot change, like a type-object's identity, and not it's field values of the moment. Since tuples are immutable their values can be safely used as keys. You could also use

```
immutable Point{T}
 x::T
 y::T
end
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like `immutable` was what I was looking for.. You can't define how classes compare to each other like java/C#'s  `bool override Equals(Object otherObject)`?

Comment: `Base.isequal`, `Base.hash`, etc. can be defined for your type

Answer (score 3):

If you define a custom `hash` method for `Point`, then things will work as you expect.